# Why Ifram http not working on heroku just locally

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, iframe, heroku

```
<iframe src="http://matrix.crebtools.com/Matrix/public/IDX.aspx?idx=5a251ec" width="860px" height="520px" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></iframe>
```

I have this code, it works locally but can't work on heroku. I guess it's for the http. I spent two days on this, please can any one help me?

On heroku it shows a white space.

Comment: I hope the site is not trying to prevent from getting loaded in an iframe - http://stackoverflow.com/a/13169145/753705

Comment: What are the response headers? You may need to allow the iframe: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Comment: Are you loading your heroku app under `http` or `https` ?

Comment: My heroku app under https

Comment: https://mohamed-hatata.herokuapp.com/   This is my link see how it look like

Comment: @nour I guess you can answer this question yourself now.